# Can an Avira Antivirus Live CD scan for viruses that would infect Ubuntu?

Tags: security, antivirus

http://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system

If I were to use that would it detect things for Windows, and for Linux?
Not just the ability to scan the filesystem, but actually look for viruses that would target Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Avira uses a modified version of Ubuntu. If they didn't remove the ext2/3/4 filesystem support, **yes, it will be able to read and scan all your NTFS and ext2/3/4 partitions.** Now, *if it's cappable of detecting **"Linux-only"** viruses, that depends of the Virus databases it uses.*

Comment: So then do you know of a scanner that does scan ext4 that is a live CD?

Comment: @LoneWolf no...

Comment: @LoneWolf Just one more question, did I answered that Avira does not do what you are asking?

Comment: Well is the answer that the Avira CD does NOT scan a linux partition?  Though I found out that an AVG Live CD can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Have not made really good experiences with avira-live-CD, cause it detects often not entirely the malware. And avira-live-CD does not run on some hardware, due to lack of drivers or due to dazuko (which only runs with Kernels of 2.4 or 2.6 ???).

You could try the rescue-CD of Kaspersky (I had with this CD better results),
which can be downloaded here :

http://support.kaspersky.com/de/4162

This distro is a Linux-Distro and real tough.
( It was Kaspersky who detected "stuxnet" and "flame" ! )

Answer (score 0):

it is Lone Wolf here.  This is the response I got from the Avira support:

"Avira Rescue System is based in Ubuntu linux live distro, it's fully compatible with ext file system and many others. It will detect any file's signature contained in Avira VDF, these signatures correspond mainly to Windows threats but not exclusively.
To accomplish full UNIX security assurance you need specialized tools.

We hope this helps."

My question is solved now.  Thanks!

Where is the solved button?